# Need to make a sha256 hash from two addresses

Tags: addresses, sha3

In solidity, what is the best way to combine two addresses? I cannot find a consistent pattern for doing this with the `address` type.

Would the recommended pattern be to convert `address` to `string`, concatenate and generate a hash?

Here's the pattern I'm attempting to achieve.

`sha3(address1 + address2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashing functions in Solidity accept a variable number of arguments:

```
function hashTwoAddresses(address a, address b) pure returns (bytes32)
{
    return sha256(a, b);
}
```